# Relation isn't showed in query with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have in model `Report` following

```
public function reportedItem()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'item_id', 'id');
}
```

In `Item` model

```
public function report()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report', 'item_id','id');
}
```

In controller

```
public function details( $item_id )
{
    $flags = Item::find($item_id)->report->unique('user_id');
    return view('flags.details', compact('flags'));
}
```

Why when I do `{{ dd(collect($flags)) }}` in my view.blade I don't see anything from `items` table even when I query it `Item::find($item_id)`?

dd output

[image]

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Report extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reports';
    protected $primaryKey = 'report_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'item_id', 'report_body', 'user_id', 'report_reason'
    ];

    public function reportedItem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'item_id', 'id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: does it return anything in the controller ? dd($flags); ?

Comment: Yes, I've got everything for `report()` but only the `item_id` from item

Comment: I think you should add ->get(); to the report model... I am not sure, haven't used laravel for a year... otherwise the query won't be executed.

Comment: in the dd relation is empty `#relations: []`

Comment: Still same result with `->get();`

Comment: can you upload a screenshot for dd($flags) inside the controller?

Comment: dd output is added. As you can see there is only Report collection. Item is missing. I mean I want to have `items` attributes in collection too. Like title, description etc, not only item_id

Comment: Can you post your reports table?

Comment: Added Report model to the question @zuif

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$flags = Item::find($item_id)->with('report')->get()
```

Comment: This gave me `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::unique()`

Comment: Item::find($item_id)->with('report')->get(); this will work :-) The reason being you can use unique when you are using find. or use 
Item::where('id',$item_id)->with('report')->unique('user_id');

Comment: I guess he wants the report with company details on it, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, just one question: How can I display values from report table also? Since both tables are in collection now?

Comment: $flags = Item::find($item_id)->with('report')->get()->toArray();
dd($flags);
There will be a key 'report' in this array that will give you the item report information. This will only give you value if you have report against that item. and if my answer works please mark as accepted to help other users :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use something like this in your controller

```
public function details( $item_id )
{
    $flags = Report::with('reportedItem')->where('item_id', '$item_id')->get();
```

Comment: This return empty item collection `Collection {#299 ▼  #items: [] }`

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
$flags = Item::with('reportedItem')->find($item_id);
```

Then when you dd($flags) this look for the "relations" tab and inside that you'll see the info.

Comment: Sorry but not working: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::reportedItem()`